# Repeatedly apply excel formula to different ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a excel [formula](https://superuser.com/questions/240858/convert-a-column-into-a-comma-separated-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=cc2dc75b9df441f1820ab718b3290d9c) for converting a column of numbers to a ; seperated list. (See solution 1 in the link).

I want to make this formula quickly and easily to apply to different columns in a variety of spreadsheets (so the column will be different). I also need to distribute the result to several users.

Is there a way to add it to a button, or perhaps the context menu on the column headers so it can easily be applied to different columns quickly

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: This kind of thing is typically done using appropriate absolute and relative addressing, and then simple copy and paste.  Can you clarify why that wouldn't work for your requirement?